# Is TE FORM + だって a possible combination?

Tags: grammar, て-form, anime, casual

```
オレは泳いでだって行くぜ
```

This sentence is from episode 9 of Digimon Adventure.

The character's brother is supposedly lost on another island and he says that.

The prior sentence for context:

```
空も飛べないのにどうやってさがしに行くんだよ
```

I want to know if that is equivalent to 泳いでも.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is rather equivalent to 泳い**でで**も(te-form of 泳ぐ + でも).

Specifically, the [だって](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/#jn-137401) means:

> ［係助］《断定の助動詞「だ」に係助詞「とて」の付いた「だとて」の音変化という》名詞・副詞、一部の助詞に付く。**「でも」に似るが、語調がより強い。**
> １ ある事柄を例示し、それが他と同類、または、同様であるという意を表す。…もやはり。**…でも**。「鯨―人間の仲間だ」「ここから―見える」

---

I think, at least in most cases, 'te-form+だって' is translatable to *even by/even if (subj) have to ...*.

- 泳いでだって行く I'll go even if I have to swim (even by swimming).
- 一万円払ってだって食べる価値がある It is worth eating even if I have to pay 10000 yen.
- 人を殺してだって生き延びたい (I) want to survive even by committing murders

All だって can be replaced by でも.